# Change between menu/buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've got this menu where you can choose the class in my game.

```
<div class="text">
<div id="story">Choose a class.</div>
<input type="button" class="knight" value="Knight"/>
<input type="button" class="mage" value="Mage"/>
<input type="button" class="archer" value="Archer"/>
</div>
```

How do I use jquery so that when I press any of these buttons, I'll get a new set of buttons which you can press to choose your race?

I've tried `.replaceWith()` but jquery won't work on the new buttons.
It will take the css.

```
function classChange() {
    var Class = $(this).val();
    $('#statsImg').text("class: " + Class);
    $('.knight').replaceWith('<input type="button" class="elf value="Elf"/>');
    $('.mage').replaceWith('<input type="button" class="human" value="Human"/>');
    $('.archer').replaceWith('<input type="button" class="Dwarf" value="Dwarf"/>');
    $('.menu').show();
};

$('.knight').click(classChange);
$('.mage').click(classChange);
$('.archer').click(classChange);
```

Button `elf` won't do anything with the next part:

```
$('.elf').on('click', '.elf',function () {
    $('#statsImg').text('test');
});
```

Works with button `knight/mage/archer`.

So what I'd like to know is how do I get rid of this menu and get a new menu once I press a button?

Sorry if I forgot to add something that you need to know. I'll add it if you need it.

Comment: There's a `"` missing after `class="elf`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `bind` the events to the buttons after adding them. Try with -

```
$('.knight').replaceWith('<input type="button" class="elf value="Elf"/>').bind('click', function() {
    $('#statsImg').text('test');
});
```

Comment: or `$('.knight').replaceWith('<input type="button" class="elf value="Elf" onclick="$('#statsImg').text('test');" />');`